# R.java is not generating drawables anymore

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

My R.java doesn't generate more than 19 images... What is hapening? How can i fix that?

Comment: check your log messages. I've once meet this situation and the problem is I have more than 64 (I guess. I can't recall the exact number) drawables.

Comment: can you explain your question clearly?
maybe you can check the drawable folder rule: [drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've cleaned your project, most likely you have introduced some XML bug that it's not telling you about.  The more recent SDK has some quirks in it and it's very easy to introduce an XML bug that you're not told about explicitly but that prevents your R class from compiling correctly. It might be in your layout, it might be in your manifest... really, any xml could be the culprit. Make sure all your images are all lower case and that you don't have any identical files with different extensions like foo.jpg and foo.png.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about you case however, my case; I use Eclipse, sometimes it doesn't generate R.java

1. Look at your XML file, make sure that is no error in your xml.
2. Refresh your project or close Eclipse and open again (or Clean your project; select `project` > clean ....but this is the last choice and you ***need*** to make sure that no error in xml file, otherwise, everything gone, i'm not sure there is the way to bring R.java back or not then) Normally, R.java will generate automatically. but sometimes, i don't know why it's a bit moron :b , but, i close Eclipse and open it again it works.